# Telegraf can not connect to Docker sock

Tags: docker, influxdb, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, telegraf-plugins

I try to gather some metrics about my Docker containers using Telegraf. I have mounted the docker sock to it but I still receive an error message. What am I missing here?

```
    volumes:
      - ./data/telegraf:/etc/telegraf
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

```
2021-10-29T20:11:30Z E! [inputs.docker] Error in plugin: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.21/containers/json?filters={"status":["running"]}&limit=0": dial unix /var/run/docker.so
```

```
[[inputs.docker]]
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  gather_services = false
  container_names = []
  source_tag = false
  container_name_include = []
  container_name_exclude = []
  timeout = "5s"
  perdevice = true
  total = false
  docker_label_include = []
  docker_label_exclude = []
  tag_env = ["JAVA_HOME", "HEAP_SIZE"]
```

Comment: Solution for docker-compose: https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/10050

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Telegraf Docker images now run the telegraf process as the `telegraf` user/group and no longer as the `root` user. In order to monitor the docker socket, which is traditionally owned by `root:docker group`, you need to pass the group into the telegraf user.

This can be done via:

```
--user telegraf:$(stat -c '%g' /var/run/docker.sock)
```

Comment: Could you add a bit of details, how this switch is supposed to be used. With version 1.20.4 of telegraf (from Docker Hub) there is no `--user` switch.

Comment: @jlandercy the `--user` switch belongs to docker run, not telegraf. Telegraf images 1.20.4 are still running with root as the main user, but the switch to telegraf user is done in the `/entrypoint.sh`

Comment: @petrtvaruzek, Yes I have figured it out, thank for answering anyway. Cheers

Comment: any other possible reasons?  I add:  "user:  telegraf:1001" to my docker compose,  stat -c '%g' /var/run/docker.sock gives: 1001

Comment: I tried using this like so in my docker compose:
--
..
telegraf3:
    image: telegraf
    user: telegraf:$$(stat -c '%g' /var/run/docker.sock)
..

But i get the error:

Error response from daemon: unable to find group $(stat -c '%g' /var/run/docker.sock): no matching entries in group file